# What is this high wing, single engine aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I think it might be a Douglas aircraft.

[image: Aircraft photograph]

Answer (score 13):

Indeed a Douglas aircraft, namely the [**O-43**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_O-43), an improved version of the [O-31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_O-31) (longer wing and a new engine) which was Douglas's first straight-wing monoplane.

The O-43 was in turn developed into the [O-46](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_O-46)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!